# search given set of files and copy to another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos

There is a given set of file names in a needToFind.txt file such as:

myImage1.jpg , theImage.jpg, parisImage.jpg (This is a flie that I will format it does not matter filee names are seperated with comma, or line break)

And there is a folder named /MyImageFolder, which contains lets say 1000 images, and also contains myImage1.jpg , theImage.jpg, parisImage.jpg

I want to find those given images and copy them to another directory.

---

### I want to search given file names in needToFind.txt, in a directory/folder MyImages, which contains many images. And copy founded images to another directory/folder, such as MyGivenSetOfImages.

Please help, this will save my life.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat is it clear now?

Comment: Clearer, but I do not know the answer. You are more likely to get help though.

Comment: How is copying a bunch of files , that too images. Gonna save your life?

Comment: @MukulGoel ok, exaggerated but save from lots of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format needToFind.txt to have one file name per line. The following simple batch script should work.

```
@echo off
cd "\MyImageFolder"
for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%F in ("needToFind.txt") do copy "%%~F" "\anotherFolder"
```

It can be done on the command line without a batch file: just change each `%%` to `%`.

Comment: needed some extension, could you pls help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382336/search-given-set-of-file-names-in-all-sub-directories-and-copy-to-another-dire

Answer (score 0):

I guess the trickiest part is to read the file

If you can , i would advice you to create text files with all names in a single lime seperated by a comma.

refer [how to read a text file through batch](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/714c5808-0971-44c1-bacc-55d5ae576515) for that

Later you could simply use the extracted variables in a simple `copy` command.

i could have provided a skeleton , but on a phone.
I hope this helps
open for questions

Comment: @tugce hope it helps, not a code if you were looking for one. But open to questions. But i think it shouldnt be a hard nut.