# search given set of file names.* in all sub directories and copy to another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos

I need extension to this question: [search given set of files and copy to another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333937/search-given-set-of-files-and-copy-to-another-directory)

There is a given set of file names in a needToFind.txt file such as:

myImage1 , theImage, parisImage (one file name per line)

And there is a folder named /MyImageFolder, which contains lets say 1000 images in its subfolders and itself, and also contains myImage1.jpg ,myImage1.png, theImage.jpg, parisImage.jpg, parisImage.png,parisImage.tiff

I want to find those given image names without looking file extension and copy them to another directory.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @dbenham needed extension on my previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd "\MyImageFolder"
for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%F in ("needToFind.txt") do copy "%%~F.*" "\anotherFolder"
```

If the provided file names already have extensions, and you want to ignore the extensions, you can use

```
@echo off
cd "\MyImageFolder"
for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%F in ("needToFind.txt") do copy "%%~nF.*" "\anotherFolder"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
cd "\MyImageFolder"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("needToFind.txt") do (
   for /R %%b in ("%%~Na.*") do copy "%%b" "\anotherFolder"
)
```